# PHP: wrap each group of words starting with the same letter within a div

Tags: php, loops

I have this loop that sorts a set of results alphabetically and shows a `<span>` with the current letter, but I can't find a way to wrap each subset within a div.

```
<?php

$previousLetter = null;

foreach($allBrands as $brand) {


    $firstLetter = strtolower($brand->name[0]);

    if ( $previousLetter != $firstLetter ) {

        echo '<span class="designer-first-letter">'. $firstLetter .'</span>';

        $previousLetter = $firstLetter;


    }

    echo '<p>'.$brand->name.'</p>';

}
```

I would like something like this

```
<div>
    <span>A</span>
    <p>Aword</p>
    <p>Aword2</p>
    <p>Aword3</p>
    <p>...</p>
</div>

<div>
    <span>B</span>
    <p>Bword</p>
    <p>Bword2</p>
    <p>Bword3</p>
    <p>...</p>
</div>

<div>
    <span>C</span>
    <p>Cword</p>
    <p>Cword2</p>
    <p>Cword3</p>
    <p>...</p>
</div>

...
```

Right now what I get is

```
<span>A</span>
<p>Aword</p>
<p>Aword2</p>
<p>Aword3</p>
<p>...</p>

<span>B</span>
<p>Bword</p>
<p>Bword2</p>
<p>Bword3</p>
<p>...</p>

<span>C</span>
<p>Cword</p>
<p>Cword2</p>
<p>Cword3</p>
<p>...</p>

...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about pre-grouping the brands before you loop through

```
$brands = Array("Aword", "Aword2", "Aword3", "BWord", "Bword2");
$groups = Array();

foreach($brands as $brand) { 
    $startsWith = strtolower($brand[0]);

    if( array_key_exists($startsWith, $groups))
        array_push($groups[$startsWith], $brand);
    else 
    {
        $groups[$startsWith] = Array($brand);
    }
}

ksort($groups);

foreach($groups as $key => $value ) {
    ?>
    <div>
        <span><?php echo strtoupper($key) ?></span>
        <?php foreach($value as $brand) { ?>
        <p><?php echo $brand?></p>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

And, ksort to make them alphabetical

Comment: Thank you very much, works perfectly. They are already alphabetically sorted because they are from a Database.

Comment: I would personally set up the underlying structure first before sorting the contents of `$brands` into it, instead of setting it up while going through `$brands`. Other than that this approach is better than trying to print `<div>` and `</div>` in the `$brands` foreach loop, as this code is much better readable.